# How to loop in parallel to alter objects inside a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop, object, multiprocessing

Here is a minimum example of my problem:

```
import concurrent.futures
from functools import partial

# Object class
class obj:
    def __init__(self,tup):
        self.tup = tup

# Function includes attributes in objects of class above
def new(fi,fdic):
    fdic[fi].new = 'work_'+ str(fdic[fi].tup)
    
# Dictionary full of instances of obj above    
dic = {'a':obj(1),
       'b':obj(2),
       'c':obj(3),
       'd':obj(4),
       'e':obj(5),
       'f':obj(6),
      }

partial_new = partial(new, fdic=dic)
```

Now I want to multiprocess all the objects in the dictionary (because I have too many in reality).
The code below runs. But it does not "work", because I actually need ProcessPool (I think? Because I want to process things in parallel).

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for _ in executor.map(partial_new, dic.keys()):
        pass
print(dic['b'].new)
```

This one does not run:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for _ in executor.map(partial_new, dic.keys()):
        pass
print(dic['b'].new)
```

My question is: How do I make this work?

I just need to use the function to modify all the objects inside the dictionary in parallel. Later I wills save the full dictionary, but the function that I apply does not return anything (if this makes things easier).

Comment: You will not get it to work in a process pool.  In a process pool, each process has its own copy of the dictionary, and each process will be modifying only its copy.  Modifying a shared data structure is not something you use multiprocessing for.

Comment: . . . You **can** use multiprocessing to build the various pieces of your data structure.  You can call a process to say "what should I set `my_dict[a]` to be.  But then your main process will have to do the actual assignment.

Comment: @FrankYellin - While I have no experiance using them couldn't [multiprocessing.shared_memory](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html) and/or [Shared ctypes Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#shared-ctypes-objects) be used?

Comment: Shared ctypes have simple values and arrays. Nothing as complicated as dictionaries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the issue that it takes a long time to calculate the new value?

```
def get_new_value(dictionary_item):
    key, value = dictionary_item
    return key, 'work_' + str(value.tup)

with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for key, new_value in executor.map(get_new_value, dic.items()):
        dic[key].new = new_value
```

You can only have one thread modifying dic.  But you can pass key and value to a thread, have the thread return the key and the new value, and then have the original thread do the work of updating the dictionary.

You'll probably want to specify a chunksize to `map`

=== edited ===

As promised, my complete file.

```
import concurrent.futures

# Object class
class obj:
    def __init__(self, tup):
        self.tup = tup


# Dictionary full of instances of obj above
dic = {'a': obj(1),
       'b': obj(2),
       'c': obj(3),
       'd': obj(4),
       'e': obj(5),
       'f': obj(6),
       }


def get_new_value(dictionary_item):
    key, value = dictionary_item
    return key, 'work_' + str(value.tup)

def go():
  with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for key, new_value in executor.map(get_new_value, dic.items()):
        dic[key].new = new_value
  # Make sure it really worked!
  for key, value in dic.items():
      print(key, value.new)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    go()
```

Comment: Your solution seems to have the same problem as mine: If I change ProcessPool to ThreadPool it works. But as it is, it gives me an error...

Yes, my original problem is that each iteration inside the loop takes 20 min. and I need 350 of them.

Comment: Oh.  That problem.  Your call to `with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor():` cannot be top-level.  It has to be inside a function.  You then call that function inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` at the bottom.

Comment: First, I forgot: Thanks for the help! Second, I am not sure if I understand... I am using a Jupyter notebook, but if I write `if __name__ == '__main__':` before calling  `with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor():` I still get the same error... I guess I am doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry.  I don't know about Jupyter notebooks.

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyway. But just for info (maybe someone else can help me, too), I get the same error if I run it on my normal Python console (not on Jupyter)...

Comment: I've about to update my answer with my complete code.  It runs just fine under Python3.8 on my Mac with I type "python3.8 myfile.py".  What error are you getting?

Comment: It works. You are a genius! Thanks a lot. I was not saving the file before running it in the console... After saving the file, it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ThreadPool` from the `multiprocess` module in the following way:

1. Create a list of the dict keys (`ls = [a for a in dict.keys()`)
2. Define a function that given a pointer to a dict and a key does the alteration you desire
3. use `ThreadPool`'s `starmap()` method to run that function on the list you created and the dict
4. join and close the thread pool

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to the parallel threads that I already have running?

Comment: Not exactly,`starmap()` and `ThreadPool` apply the function in a different manner than what you wrote.